# Using PHP to run a post action rather than from a form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

This is homework and we are required to use PHP. We can't use javascript unless absolutely necessary.

My current form is in my first PHP document. On the click of the submission button, it posts to itself to verify and check data. I used this to get styling changes using PHP within the one document.

If everything verifies, it will action post to a new PHP with the same data that had just been posted.

My form is built from 3 text inputs, one set of radio buttons (3 buttons), and one set of checkboxes (4 checkboxes). Once they're all verified, I need to post that data to a new PHP document for processing.

Here is my current code:

```
            // Are all fields fill
            if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
                $isCodeCorrect = checkStatusCodeCorrect();
                $isTextCorrect = checkStatusTextCorrect();
                $isShareOptionCorrect = checkRadioButtonCorrect();
                $isDateCorrect = checkDateCorrect();
                $isPermissionsCorrect = checkPermissionsCorrect();

                if($isCodeCorrect&&$isTextCorrect&&$isShareOptionCorrect&&$isDateCorrect&&$isPermissionsCorrect){
                    $mainFormAction='action="poststatusprocess.php"';
                }
            }

            function checkStatusCodeCorrect() {
                if(!empty($_POST['statusCode'])){
                    $str1 = $_POST['statusCode'];
                    //Only S0001 style code
                    $statusCodePattern = "/^S\d{4}$/";
                    if(preg_match($statusCodePattern, $str1)){
                        return true;
                    }else return false;
                }else return false;
            }
            function checkStatusTextCorrect() {
                if(!empty($_POST['statusText'])){
                    $str2 = $_POST['statusText'];
                    //Only a-z, A-Z, commas, explanation marks, question marks, apostraphese, and full stops. Case insensitive and global searching and any white space
                    $statusTextPattern = "/([a-z,!?'\.\s])/i"; 
                    if(preg_match($statusTextPattern, $str2)){
                        return true;
                    }else return false; 
                }else return false;
            }
            function checkRadioButtonCorrect() {
                return !empty($_POST['shareOption']);
            }
            function checkDateCorrect() {
                if(!empty($_POST['date'])){
                    $str3 = $_POST['date'];
                    //Only 2 digits then forward slash, then 2 digits then forward slash and then only 2 or 4 digits for the year
                    $datePattern = "/^((\d\d)+\-\d{2}\-\d{2})$/"; 
                    if(preg_match($datePattern, $str3)){
                        return true;
                    }else return false;
                }else return false;
            }
            function checkPermissionsCorrect(){
                if((!empty($_POST['allowLike']))||(!empty($_POST['allowComment']))||(!empty($_POST['allowShare']))||(!empty($_POST['allowNone']))){
                    return true;
                }else return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CURL if you have the modules installed, alternatively because this is homework you are probably expected to learn and understand how to do it manually.

```
/**
 * Send a POST request without using PHP's curl functions.
 *
 * @param string $url The URL you are sending the POST request to.
 * @param array $postVars Associative array containing POST values.
 * @return string The output response.
 * @throws Exception If the request fails.
 */
function post($url, $postVars = array()){
    //Transform our POST array into a URL-encoded query string.
    $postStr = http_build_query($postVars);
    //Create an $options array that can be passed into stream_context_create.
    $options = array(
        'http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST', //We are using the POST HTTP method.
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postStr //Our URL-encoded query string.
            )
    );
    //Pass our $options array into stream_context_create.
    //This will return a stream context resource.
    $streamContext  = stream_context_create($options);
    //Use PHP's file_get_contents function to carry out the request.
    //We pass the $streamContext variable in as a third parameter.
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $streamContext);
    //If $result is FALSE, then the request has failed.
    if($result === false){
        //If the request failed, throw an Exception containing
        //the error.
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception('POST request failed: ' . $error['message']);
    }
    //If everything went OK, return the response.
    return $result;
}
```

(Taken from [here](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-post-request-without-curl/))

This function will send a POST request from within PHP code, then once you have validated all the fields with your single page form, you can call it with:

```
try{
    $result = post('processValidated.php', array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'field' => 'Value'
    ));
    echo $result;
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As mentioned, this is not really a standard way or handling form input and data validation. If it is a small stand alone form both the invalid and valid form submissions are handled by the one php script, or by included classes if using OOP. Alternatively an MVC framework will use controllers etc to validate and process form submissions and respond accordingly

Comment: This didn't work the way I thought it would but it did work. I'll mark this as answering since it does technically answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Just include the function from the other file and run if all checks pass.  Alternatively you can redirect to the new url, but that would become a get not a post. Usually you handle all the post requests in one place and do an http header redirect to some result page.